# Principles behind when to use an optional type in Swift?

Tags: swift, oop, option-type

When designing classes/structs in Swift, what are the best practices for identifying when you should use an Optional type?

For example, lets say I'm mapping a JSON response to a `Photo` object and there is a property `photographerName` which is just a string. Sometimes we receive empty strings for the field `photographerName` by the response.

Should my `Photo` object use a `String?` type and assign it to nil? Or use a `String` type and set it to an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the application architecture and data structures that you going to use in the application.

There is no rule that will describe how properly use optional chaining in the application architecture.

At first, we should know what is [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If
>   the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call
>   succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript
>   call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the
>   entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

Based on my experience, I am using optional values in my data structure when I clearly could not define if my model could or could not have some relationship or property.

Example:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let email: String
    var friends: [String]?

    init(name: String, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
    }
}

let user = User(name: "Oleg", email: "Oleg@email.com")
```

I know that user will have name and email but I do not know if he would have any friends. Also, in this way, I could prevent my code from execution of operation on `nil` objects.

In case that you describe it really depends on the architecture of the application and requirements. For example, should we show placeholder if `photographerName` is empty or not? Are any additional operation that are using `photographerName` property?

Answer (score 1):

It´s up to you what you like to use, but if you receive a response with a property that can be `nil` then you should use `optional` and handle it in the code.

Something like this:

```
struct Photo {
    let photographerName: String?

    init(photographerName: String? = nil) {
        self.photographerName = photographerName
    }
}
```

And then in your code to check if `photographerName` has a value:

```
if let photographerName = photo.photographerName {
    // use photographerName in here
}
```

Comment: you only would need one init if you would use nil as default `init(photographerName: String? = nil) `